# Does this description warrant the tort of deceit?

Tags: tort, online

Hello I am concerned someone online has recently used Reddit to offer someone £180 through Paypal for £200 of Amazon gift card codes with the intention of not giving him the £180. The Person with the £200 gave him the codes first and now he has redeemed them and has not given the £180 that he had stated previously.

Comment: Yeah the seller can sue the buyer for the money. But since this was done online you will need to figure out the jurisdiction

Comment: How could i find out the jurisdiction?

Comment: Probably where the guy lives is the jurisdiction you'll have to sue in

Answer (score 0):

There is no tort of deceit here - this is a straight up breach of contract.